# How do you copy data from a DB on one SQL server to a DB on another SQL server?

Tags: sql-server

I'm not trying to do a straight copy of the data from one server to the other. I have to clean up/rename the source data before inserting it into the destination DB, and check if values exist in various look up tables and insert them if they don't.

Basically something like this:

```
SELECT EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName, Region
INTO #Temp
FROM server1.db1.dbo.Employees

INSERT INTO server2.db2.dbo.Region
(Region)
SELECT DISTINCT Region FROM #Temp
WHERE Region NOT IN (SELECT Region FROM server2.db2.dbo.Region)

INSERT INTO server2.db2.dbo.Employees
(EmployeeID, FullName, Region)
SELECT EmployeeID, FirstName + ' ' + LastName AS FullName, Region FROM #Temp

DROP TABLE #Temp
```

However, using a fully qualified name like serverName.DBname.DBTable doesn't seem to work.

I'm using SQL Server 2012.

EDIT -- I don't believe I can get the client to create a linked server as per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-addlinkedserver-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017.

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't seem to work"? To reference the data on the server (& database) you're connected to you'll only need to use 2 part naming, but for the other provided that it's a linked server 4 part naming would work fine.

Comment: @Larnu When I try to use 4 part naming, everything is highlighted red and it complains that it `Could not find server 'serverName' in sys.servers`.

Comment: The red is intellisense, and it can't get details of objects on a linked server; that doesn't mean the object does not exist. The latter error, however, means that you haven't configured the remote server as a linked server

Comment: @Larnu ok. Well that's a problem since I can't get the client to link their servers.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't set up a linked server (which I recommend you do), you could use `OPENROWSET`. This **assumes** you have an AD account on both instances, with the relevant permissions. You will also need to connect to the instance you want to insert the data into, not the server the data is coming from. This should give you the idea:

```
USE db2;
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Employees (EmployeeID, FullName, Region)
SELECT EmployeeID, FirstName + ' ' + LastName AS FullName, Region
FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI','SERVER=server2;Trusted_Connection=yes',
                N'SELECT EmployeeID, FirstName, LastName, Region FROM db1.dbo.Employees');
```

If you don't have an AD login on both, you'll need to use SQL Authentication instead. if that isn't an option, then you'll have to go down a different path entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use SSIS.

1. Create connection managers to each server
2. Create a data flow task.
3. Add sources and destinations to the data flow tasks for each table.
4. Put your transformation queries into the sources, connected to your source server.
5. Map your columns in your destinations, connected to your destination server.
6. Execute the package.
7. Bob's your uncle.

This also assumes you have rights on both boxes, but you shouldn't need to ask anything of your client to get it done.

Comment: I've not used SSIS before but I attempted this in a test environment. Unfortunately after doing the above, everything seemed to execute fine and I got all green check marks, checked the data viewer and everything looked good between source and destination. But afterwards no new data appeared in the destination DB. I'm sure I'm missing something due to my unfamiliarity with SSIS.

Comment: That's unexpected. I'd check the connection manager for the destination database and make sure you're pointing to the server & database you intended. I've worked on boxes where there were, say, a test and dev database on the same server, and they had the same schemas, so it would be possible to point to the wrong database. Same thing with dev & test servers. It seems likely the data went _somewhere_, or it would've thrown an error.